# PHP character decoding

Tags: php

I have an array of strings coming back from a web service that are encoded like this:

> "Women\x27s Health"

I have not been able to convert "\x27" to an apostrophe in PHP.  I've tried

```
html_entity_decode('Women\x27s Health", ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')
```

and a few other solutions outside of a find an replace is there a way to do this?

Comment: What format is the data coming back to you in?

Comment: JSON - the comment below worked for me.

Comment: Whoever is providing this data is not doing it correctly. Apostrophes don't need to be escaped. If they did, they should be done like `\u0027`, which would then get handled by `json_decode()` automatically.

Comment: It's our google search appliance.  It probably has a setting somewhere to change how it's returning the data.  I'll take a look.  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2):

It's not really "encoded" ... Just apply [stripcslashes()](https://secure.php.net/stripcslashes).